# Header of Page with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, visual-studio, header, itext

I am doing a pdf document with iTextSharp. I created the header with PageEvent event, but I want that my header to be different in some pages.
It works to setting the same header for all pages.

But, I wish for something different.

Example: Page 1=>Header 1 Page 2=>Header 1 Page 3=>Header 2 Page 4=>Header 2

I would solve it, but the troubles come when this happens:

```
writer.PageEvent=new PDFFooter(params);    
doc.Open();
```

The PageEvent event must be created above `doc.Open();` when I put it below, it generates an error. I am using C# with Visual Studio Community 2013.

How would I solve this? Thanks!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add Header and Footer for PDF using iTextsharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18996323/add-header-and-footer-for-pdf-using-itextsharp)

Comment: Consider counting the `OnEndPage` calls and acting different in that method depending on the count.

Comment: Please read [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html) (a free ebook) and you'll discover that your question is a duplicate of [How to generate a report with dynamic header in PDF using itextsharp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628429/itextsharp-how-to-generate-a-report-with-dynamic-header-in-pdf-using-itextsharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem now.

The solution was this:

```
PDFFooter events=new PDFFooter();

PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, Response.OutputStream);

doc.Open();
foreach (var item in ListReporte)
{                    
   events = new PDFFooter();
   writer.PageEvent = events;
   events.Ciudad = item.Ciudad;
   events.OnStartPage(writer,doc);
   //This was the solution
   if (writer.PageEvent != null)
      writer.PageEvent = null;
 }
```

In each iteration, I assign null to PageEvent property.

But first, I created a PDFFooter object (The class PDFFooter contains OnStartPage and OnEndPages events...), So, in that class I declared some attributes about the data that I wanted to display.

Previously, I couldn't instantiate the PDFFooter class below of `doc.Open()`. The code was like this:

```
writer.PageEvent=new PDFFooter();
doc.Open():
```

So, I tried to create the objet first and then set it to PageEvent property of writer object (I recommend to do this). And It worked.

It feels wonderful.